# Groovy with replaceAll with wildcards

Tags: regex, groovy

Working on a script that will parse some of my java files. I am trying to use replaceAll() to get rid of some of the things that I do not need. So of it is static stuff which is easy, but some are harder.

```
MyWebsiteTests extends MYbaseTest {
```

So for this one I want to remove the extends and anything after it on that line. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do it:

```
line.replaceAll( /(.+)\sextends.*$/, '$1' )
```

Parsing source code with regex always seems to end in tears though...

Comment: @jrock2004 should do... `assert 'MyWebsiteTests' == 'MyWebsiteTests extends MYbaseTest {'.replaceAll( /(.+)\sextends.*$/, '$1' )` works for me...

Comment: +1 for _"Parsing source code with regex always seems to end in tears "_

Answer (score 2):

***Groovy:***

```
assert expected == before.replaceFirst(/\s+extends\s.*/, '')
```

or

```
assert expected == before.replaceAll(/\s+extends\s.*/, '')
```

Comment: @jrock2004 - Please accept this answer by clicking check mark under the number left of the answer (hover mouse pointer under the number to show check mark).